# Clang integrated assembler and "invalid operand for instruction"

Tags: c, assembly, clang, llvm, inline-assembly

We are using Clang in a default configuration. In the default configuration, Clang's Integrated Assembler is used (and not the system assembler, like GAS). I'm having trouble determining the exact problem (and fix) for:

```
$ make
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -Wall -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c gcm.cpp
...
gcm.cpp:676:3: error: invalid operand for instruction
                AS2(    movd    WORD_REG(di), xmm...
                ^
./cpu.h:221:20: note: expanded from macro 'AS2'
        #define AS2(x, y) GNU_AS2(x, y)
                          ^
./cpu.h:216:27: note: expanded from macro 'GNU_AS2'
        #define GNU_AS2(x, y) "\n\t" #x ", " #y ";"
                             ^
<inline asm>:110:12: note: instantiated into assembly here
        movd rdi, xmm0;
                  ^~~~~
gcm.cpp:685:3: error: invalid operand for instruction
                AS2(    movd    WORD_REG(di), xmm...
                ^
./cpu.h:221:20: note: expanded from macro 'AS2'
        #define AS2(x, y) GNU_AS2(x, y)
                          ^
./cpu.h:216:27: note: expanded from macro 'GNU_AS2'
        #define GNU_AS2(x, y) "\n\t" #x ", " #y ";"
                                 ^
<inline asm>:117:12: note: instantiated into assembly here
        movd rdi, xmm1;
                  ^~~~~
```

I ***think*** the errors above may be related to [Inline Assembly and Compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm). But as far as I know, `rdi` is 64-bits, `xmm1` is 128-bits, and the `movd` specifies the operand size, so the compatibility issue should not apply.

What is the problem with the code above?

---

You can examine the source file online at [Crypto++ gcm.cpp Source File](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/gcm_8cpp_source.html). The issue should be easy to duplicate if you have Clang installed:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-asm
cd cryptopp-asm
export CXX=clang++
make GAS210_OR_LATER=1 GAS219_OR_LATER=1 GAS219_OR_LATER=1
```

Or:

```
# Try to make just gcm.o
make GAS210_OR_LATER=1 GAS219_OR_LATER=1 GAS219_OR_LATER=1 gcm.o
```

The odd looking `make` line is due to [LLVM Bug 24200 - With integrated assembler enabled, failed to fetch version string of assembler](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24200).

Comment: I don't see `r/m64, xmm` being listed as a valid operand combination for `MOVD` in Intel's manual. Did you mean to use `MOVQ` (or `edi` instead of `rdi`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r/m64, xmm` is not listed as a valid operand combination for the `MOVD` instruction in Intel's Software Developers' Manual. However, the following two forms are supported:

```
MOVD r/m32, xmm
SSE2 Move doubleword from xmm register to r/m32.

MOVQ r/m64, xmm
SSE2 Move quadword from xmm register to r/m64.
```

Which makes me suspect that the `MOVD` instruction needs to be a `MOVQ` when building for 64-bit targets, or that `rdi` is supposed to be replaced by `edi` (although that might affect other parts of the code that rely on the top 32 bits of `rdi`).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Today is literally my day to clear all these remaining issues with Clang... It looks like the same few sets of problems are being encountered on a recurring basis...

Comment: @Peter - forgive my ignorance... Are you saying I need to set the high 32-bits of `rdi` to 0 before the `movq`? Or maybe set the high 32-bits of `xmm1` to 0 after the `movq`? Or is it operational minusca that I can safely ignore?

Comment: `movd edi,xmm1` would clear the high 32 bits of `rdi`.

Comment: Yep, this means 32bit ops don't depend on the previous value of the register (short dep chains are very important for out-of-order execution / register renaming).  It also means you can use 32bit ops, and then use it in a 64bit context.  (e.g. as part of an address: `inc ecx / mov eax, [rdi + 4*rcx]`)

Comment: Michael, Peter - `movq rdi, xmm0` did not compile (*register %rdi is only available in 64-bit mode*), so it was not the `movq`. `movd edi, xmm0` compiled, but the program failed its self tests.... I could scream right around now... I'm going to have to keep working on this :(

Comment: Are you building for a 32-bit or 64-bit target (or both)? Perhaps you need to `#define` a macro that expands to `movd` or `movq` depending on the target bitness, similar to how `WORD_REG` adds either an `e` or `r` prefix.